# Hide window shadow

Tags: delphi, window, tooltip, shadow

I made a program in Delphi that watches for a window and make it invisible when it is created. The window became invisible correctly but its shadow remains forever on the desktop (until next restart). The window I want to hide it is the today tooltip that you can see when holding the mouse on the time in systray in Windows 7 & 8. How can I hide the shadow?

This is the code:

```
h := FindWindow('ClockTooltipWindow', nil);
if (IsWindow(h)) then ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
```

This is a picture of remaining shadows:
[image]

Comment: Er, how is your code hiding the window. That would appear to be the key!

Comment: Windows API function ShowWindow(hwnd, False);

Comment: Don't just describe it, better show your code!

Comment: @jachguate I've added the code to the question.

Comment: And when do you call this? How are you synchronizing with the other process? I presume this is cross-process.

Comment: May be this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/243922/tooltips-shadow-stuck-on-desktop

Comment: Can duplicate it. Don't know why it happens. As a workaround, it seems that, you can resize the window such that it won't draw its shadow. E.g., before hiding: `SetWindowPos(h,0,0,0,1,1,SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);`

Comment: .. on a side note, one wonders what's offending about the tooltip..

Comment: @David Heffernan I call the code in a timer.

Comment: You answered just one of my questions. In any case, unless we can see it happening, how can we diagnose what the problem is. Show us a reproduction.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe Most of my program users want to have shadows!

Comment: @David Heffernan I uploaded an image of shadows. You can make same program simple by placing a timer on the form and put the code into ontimer event.

Comment: @Vahid You want each potential answered to do that rather than you?

Comment: @David Heffernan If you want the exe file you can download it from http://www.4shared.com/zip/UVl8MHcL/test.html

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz Thank you! Please post your answer, then I'll be able to mark it as right answer.

Comment: @Vahid - Done. And you're welcome!

Comment: @Vahid Please never post *compiled* executables and expect us to download them. Just post your code. EXE files are the most major gateway to sneaking viruses/trojans/spyware into peoples' computers. Not that we don't trust you, but we don't trust anyone.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge That's exactly why I did not posted the file first. I myself prefer to write code instead of downloading files.

Comment: @Vahid well it's not about preference, it's about security. I'm surprised StackOverflow doesn't have strict rules against it for that reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an interesting/very sticking artifact, possibly the shadow gets some special treatment from the video driver. I don't know why/how it happens, maybe the tooltip just doesn't care removing its shadow when it is about to be destroyed once it is hidden.

As a workaround you can resize the tooltip before hiding to a size that it won't draw its shadow, like:

```
h := FindWindow('ClockTooltipWindow', nil);
if (IsWindow(h)) then begin
  SetWindowPos(h, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);
  ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

However the better approach in my opinion would be to nicely ask it be gone:

```
h := FindWindow('ClockTooltipWindow', nil);
if (IsWindow(h)) then 
  PostMessage(h, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```